# Unity - How to stop the rest of the game and keeping the Gameover Menu Script active

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, monogame

I am developing a game in Unity3D , the situation is that I do not know how to pause the game while I perform another task on Screen using Script. 
Let me explain this : 

 **I am parsing XML question from my Web Interface to the Unity Game.**  I need to pause the game when I display a question using a script. I am unable to **Pause** the game while keeping the ***Question Displaying Script enabled*** simltaneously. despite putting a lot of effort from different forums suggestions.

I need to do it without **TimeScale**.

P.S. Its a 2-D game.

Comment: What is the issue with using the `TimeScale`?

Comment: the most common solution to this common problem is to use your own timer to update every custom object that should be updated in your game. then you can simply pause your custom timer.